# How add up values from multiple SQL columns based on occurrances

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I need select values from a table and returns the total hours for all categories and their occurrences. The challenge is that there are different totals for each occurrence.

My query:

```
SELECT c.Category,
       c.HrsFirstOccur,
       c.HrsAddlOccur,
       COUNT(*) AS Occurrences
FROM dbo.Categories sc
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories c 
    ON sc.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderHistory oh 
    ON sc.GONumber = oh.OrderNumber
    AND sc.Item = oh.ItemNumber
WHERE sc.BusinessGroupID = 1
    AND oh.OrderNumber = 500
    AND oh.ItemNumber = '100'
GROUP BY c.Category, c.HrsFirstOccur, c.HrsAddlOccur
```

returns the following results:

| Category | HrsFirstOccur | HrsAddlOccur | Occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inertia | 24 | 16 | 2 |
| Lights | 1 | 0.5 | 4 |
| Labor | 10 | 0 | 1 |

The total is calculated based on the number of occurrences.  The first one is totaled then for each additional occurrence, the HrsAddlOccur is used.

My final result should be (24 + 16) + (1 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5) + 10 for a grand total of 52.5.

How do I loop and process the results to total this up?

Comment: You don't loop, SQL is set based, so you find the correct set operation, you might want to research window functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The total is calculated based on the number of occurrences. The first one is totaled then for each additional occurrence, the HrsAddlOccur is used.

SQL databases understand arithmetic. You can perform the computation on each row. As I understand, the logic you want is:

```
SELECT 
    c.Category,
    c.HrsFirstOccur,
    c.HrsAddlOccur,
    COUNT(*) AS Occurrences,
    c.HrsFirstOccur + ( COUNT(*) - 1 ) * HrsAddlOccur As Total
FROM ... < rest of your query > ..
```

Later on you can aggregate the whole resultset to get the grand total:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) GrandTotal
FROM (
    ... < above query > ..
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sum them simply up

```
WITH CTE as(SELECT c.Category,
               c.HrsFirstOccur,
               c.HrsAddlOccur,
               COUNT(*) AS Occurrences
             FROM dbo.Categories sc
             INNER JOIN dbo.Categories c ON sc.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
             INNER JOIN dbo.OrderHistory oh ON sc.GONumber = oh.OrderNumber
                                        AND sc.Item = oh.ItemNumber
             WHERE sc.BusinessGroupID = 1
                   AND oh.OrderNumber = 500
                   AND oh.ItemNumber = '100')
    SELECT SUM(HrsFirstOccur + (CAST((Occurrences -1) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) * HrsAddlOccur)) as total FROM CTE
```

it would do it like the example

```
CREATE TABLE CTE
    ([Category] varchar(7), [HrsFirstOccur] int, [HrsAddlOccur] DECIMAL(8,2), [Occurrences] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO CTE
    ([Category], [HrsFirstOccur], [HrsAddlOccur], [Occurrences])
VALUES
    ('Inertia', 24, 16, 2),
    ('Lights', 1, 0.5, 4),
    ('Labor', 10, 0, 1)
;
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT SUM(HrsFirstOccur + (CAST((Occurrences -1) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) * HrsAddlOccur)) as total

 FROM CTE
```

| total |
| --- |
| 52.5000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lsJDJRa4)